# Maven delete resources after testing

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, logback, maven-resources-plugin

I recently read you can have a `logback.xml` and a `logback-test.xml` in your classpath, where the test file has higher priority.

> 1. Logback tries to find a file called logback-test.xml in the classpath.
> 2. If no such file is found, logback tries to find a file called logback.groovy in the classpath.
> 3. If no such file is found, it checks for the file logback.xml in the classpath..

[Source](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html)

So I thought it would be a great idea letting logging happen in the console while testing and log to a file after buildung with maven (without having to change the output manually).
I found the `maven-resources-plugin`, which can `<exclude>` some resources. I specified test files (like `logback-test.xml`) like this in the plugin:

`pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>test/**</exclude>
                    <exclude>*test*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Which works great, but has one problem. I definitely need access to the `*test*` files (yes, also `logback-test.xml`, so I cannot just exclude only it instead of the wildcard `*test*`) and the `test/**` directory during tests. I only want to exclude/delete them after testing is complete. With this configuration the excluded resources are never copied, but I want them to the copied first (to make them accessible by tests) and then (after tests run successfully), delete them.

How can I achieve this? I've been lookung for a "maven delete plugin" but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution.

Delete the `maven-resource-plugin`. Instead, based on your packaging, use `maven-jar-plugin` or `maven-war-plugin` which is responsible for building the `jar` or `war` file (and runs later, after the tests).

---

## jar

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>test/**</exclude>
            <exclude>*test*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

## war

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>${webdir}/test/**,${webdir}/*test*</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

where `webdir` is the path to your classpath root from the built war file. You can add it to your `<properties>` tag (directly under the `<project>` tag). In my case it is `WEB-INF/classes`.

`pom.xml`

```
<properties>
    <webdir>WEB-INF/classes</webdir>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

Things are much simpler.
Maven separate sources/resources for the packaged application and sources/resources for the execution tests.
Simply move `logback-test.xml` in the `src/test/resources` folder. 
And place `logback.xml` in  `src/main/resources`.

In this way, `logback-test.xml` will be available during the tests of your build.
And as the file is located in `src/test/resources`, it will never be included it in your application.
While the packaged application will contain and use only `logback.xml` as defined in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Okay, that's good to know. But when the test files are only in `resources/test/` they are not available in normal run. I want the Application Tests to use exactly the same resources as a "normal" program run, but when I build with maven, I want none of the test files to appear in the jar. Or am I fundamentally doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have the feeling that what you call "tests" are not unit tests in `src/test/java` but manual tests in `src/main/java`. Is it the case ?

Comment: No, my tests are in `src/test/java/[package]/[Name]ApplicationTests.java`

Comment: Clarification: I do have automated Tests in `src/test/java/[package]/[Name]ApplicationTests.java` but yes, I **also** do test manually sometimes. Is this a bad thing to do?